# TTNavigator popViewController?

Tags: iphone, three20, ttnavigator

Is there a TTNavigator equivalent to UINavigationController's popViewController? (or an alternative method to dismiss a view controller that I can't find?)

Answer (score 2):

Through some quick googling I found this page: http://api.three20.info/interface_t_t_navigator.php

I think this is the method you are looking for:

> > (void)    - removeAllViewControllers
> >         Removes all view controllers from the window and releases them.

Answer (score 2):

You can access the navigation controller through the TTNavigator and call popViewControllerAnimated. Something like this:

```
[[TTNavigator navigator].topViewController.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Sadly, that pops the top view controller, only to show the same view controller underneath. I'm not sure what three20 is doing internally to cause that to occur.

Answer (score 0):

I use the code below, and I do get a warning, but it works as expected.

`[[TTNavigator navigator].visibleViewController.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];`